# How do i convert the output of Mongoose.find

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have structure like this

```
 adminID: { type: String, default: "" },
  consumableCats: [{
    consumableCatName: { type: String, default: "" },
    .....
    consumables: [{
      name: { type: String, default: "" },
      ....
      _id:....
       
      }]
    }]
  }],
```

I make a mongoose.find() and i exclude all fields inside consumables except for id

```
Store.findOne({
                '_id': req.params.id

            }, {'consumableCats.consumables.name': 0,
                ...
                'consumableCats.consumables.preparationLocation': 0,
                '__v': 0
            });
```

and i get this:

```
"consumables": [
                {
                    "_id": "5d1d114314f9ae439965904d"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5d1de09fce3d033fb0b50bcf"
                },
                ..
                ]
```

when i want to get just an array of IDs like

```
"consumables": [
        "T7LmaegQO22sE6fB7L8hmLPGrhKwxNnb",
        "lSYZTp44_yPVnXeZXr3NaaWi_m2PgsIS",
        .....
    ]
```

any ideas?

Comment: You have to do it in your code consumables.map(item => item._id);

Answer (score 0):

First you store the returned array in a variable called consumables.

```
let consumables  = [  //you get this array from mongoose.find()
            {
                "_id": "5d1d114314f9ae439965904d"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5d1de09fce3d033fb0b50bcf"
            }
            ]
```

You can create a new Empty array `let resultArray = []`
Then you can iterate over each element in the `consumables` array of objects and push it to the result array like this:

```
consumables.forEach(val=>{resultArray.push(val._id)});

console.log(resultArray); // returns ["5d1d114314f9ae439965904d","5d1de09fce3d033fb0b50bcf"]
```

Hope this has solved your issue.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up doing something like what you proposed. I also needed to convert the mongoose result to Object (store.toObject()) to make references to its attributes.

Comment: Great! Please consider upvoting the answer